# Umbraco call C# in XSLT, decode fXML output

Tags: xml, xslt, umbraco, umbraco-tags

I'm calling a C# function from XSLT in Umbraco 4.7.1.
My function is returning value of the "tag" property on current node, problem is my output is encoded.

In xsltExtensions.config I have added an assembly extension.

In my XSLT I'm getting the value of my function

```
<xsl:value-of select="TagHelpers:ShowAllTags()" />
```

My C# function:

```
  public string ShowAllTags()
        {
            var node = new DynamicNode(Node.GetCurrent());
            var html = new StringBuilder();

        if (node.HasProperty("tags"))
        {
            var tagList = node.GetPropertyValue("tags");
            if(tagList.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (var tag in tagList)
                {
                    html.Append(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(tag));
                }
            }
        }

        return html.ToString();
```

My output looks like:

> %3c%3fxml+version%3d%221.0%22%3f%3e%0d%0a%3cClientValue+xmlns%3axsd%3d%22http%3a%2f%2fwww.w3.org%2f2001%2fXMLSchema%22+xmlns%3axsi%3d%22http%3a%2f%2fwww.w3.org%2f2001%2fXMLSchema-instance%22%3e%0d%0a++%3cTags%3e%0d%0a++++%3cstring%3efritidsjob%3c%2fstring%3e%0d%0a++++%3cstring%3elo%3c%2fstring%3e%0d%0a++++%3cstring%3ejobpatrulje%3c%2fstring%3e%0d%0a++%3c%2fTags%3e%0d%0a++%3cGroupName%3edefault%3c%2fGroupName%3e%0d%0a%3c%2fClientValue%3e

But should be:

> fritidsjob, jobpatrulje, lo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get rid of the encoding by adding disable-output-encoding="yes" to your xslt select, e.g.`<xsl:value-of select="TagHelpers:ShowAllTags()" disable-output-encoding="yes" />`

However, it looks like your tags are being stored as XML, rather than a comma separated string. Which tag control are you using?